# How to add custom contact fields to the user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to add some custom fields to the user profile but for some reason it does not work.

I added the following code to the functions.php:

```
 //FUNCTION for custom profile fields
function modify_contact_methods($user_contactmethods) {

    // Add new fields
    $user_contactmethods['user-address'] = 'Address';
    $user_contactmethods['user-telephone'] = 'Telephone';
    $user_contactmethods['user-avatar'] = 'Avatar';

    return $user_contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

It looks fine to me but I still don't see the new fields in the user profile in admin.
Do I have to do anything besides this code to make it work? Or maybe my code is wrong?
Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Code is 100% right might be some predefined user_contactmethods filter in some plugins add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods',99);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems correct. Have you checked by adding some priority in filter. You can do like this

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods',99);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for add extra user fields in wordpress.

Plugin for add extra user fields

```
extra-user-fields



http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-user-fields/
```